# handling numeric null values using copy command in amazon redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

while trying to load data to redshift using s3 I am getting an error

> `Invalid digit, Value 'N', Pos 0, Type: Decimal`

its failing while trying to load NULL value to a numeric datatype column (column is nullable)

although i am using NULL AS '\000' conversion.

```
COPY campaign
FROM 's3://test/campaign.csv' 
credentials '------------------' 
EMPTYASNULL
NULL AS '\000' 
delimiter ',' 
region '----';
```

how can we handle such scenarios?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE campaign ( 
  name VARCHAR(255) SORTKEY NOT NULL, 
  discount_med DECIMAL(5,2), 
  discount_packages DECIMAL(5,2), 
  discount_test DECIMAL(5,2) 
);
```

Sample input:

> test1,5.25,NULL,1

Comment: Can you please post the example rows from the CSV, as well as table schema?

Comment: @denismo CREATE TABLE campaign
(
  name                VARCHAR(255) SORTKEY NOT NULL,
  discount_med        DECIMAL(5,2),
  discount_packages   DECIMAL(5,2),
  discount_test       DECIMAL(5,2)
);   input  test1,5.25,NULL,1    Its failing at 3rd column

Comment: I am getting same error while trying to load NULL value in boolean data type using copy command                 1,Customer cancelled the order,2,NULL,NULL,1,2016-02-17 11:48:22,NULL,0,NULL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `NULL AS '\000'` use `NULL as 'NULL'`. This worked for me on your table and data:

```
COPY campaign
FROM 's3://denis-stackoverflow/campaign.csv'
credentials '---'
NULL AS 'NULL'
EMPTYASNULL
delimiter ','
region 'ap-southeast-2';
```

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, I had to change NULL to null. Case matters for null values in the file you upload.

Comment: also, this only works for csv formatted files : psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: NULL AS argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY