# How to COPY null values into Redshift for integer columns, using the default \N for null values?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541160/handling-numeric-null-values-using-copy-command-in-amazon-redshift) one, but I don't want to change the default `NULL AS` value. I have a CSV file on S3, where an integer column is exported as "\N". Example row definition:

```
integer,string,string,integer
```

Row value:

```
4,"mystring","\N","\N"
```

This row will fail with the following for the integer column, but not the string column: `Invalid digit, Value 'N', Pos 0, Type: Short`

It seems that using `\N` works only for string columns, but the docs don't say what to do for integers.

COPY statement is like so:

```
COPY table FROM 's3location'
CREDENTIALS '----'
delimiter ',' removequotes ESCAPE COMPUPDATE ON ACCEPTINVCHARS
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-emptyasnull) that points out the default null value for the integer type.

Therefore, you must transform "\N" into empty for integer columns.

i.e.
If a row in your example is all NULL

```
,"\N","\N",
```